# Excel VBS Save output to directory the script was launched from

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Updated code: The script executes but doesn't output anything and Excel.exe process continues  to run. I need this to output to the directory the .vbs script was launched from and name the Excel file something other than Book1.xls

```
Option Explicit

Dim strFile, strGroupDN, objGroup, objExcel, intRow, objMember, objSheet
Dim objRootDSE, strDNSDomain, objTrans, strNetBIOSDomain, strGroup


Const ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC = 3
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4 = 3
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779 = 1


Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")


Set objTrans = CreateObject("NameTranslate")
objTrans.Init ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC, ""
objTrans.Set ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779, strDNSDomain
strNetBIOSDomain = objTrans.Get(ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4)

strNetBIOSDomain = Left(strNetBIOSDomain, _
Len(strNetBIOSDomain) - 1)

strGroup = InputBox("Enter AD group name")


On Error Resume Next
objTrans.Set ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4, strNetBIOSDomain & "\" & strGroup
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
On Error GoTo 0

Wscript.Echo "Group " & strGroup & " not found"
Wscript.Quit
End If
strGroupDN = objTrans.Get(ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779)

Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & strGroupDN)

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 100


Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objSheet.Name = "AD Group Members"

intRow = 1
For Each objMember In objGroup.Members
objSheet.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = objMember.sAMAccountName
intRow = intRow + 1
Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
cwd = fso.GetAbsolutePathName("*.*")
filename = fso.BuildPath(cwd, "output.xls")
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename
```

Answer (score 1):

[SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) is a method; so change

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs = ThisWorkbook.Path
```

to

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path
```

**On second thought:**

Where does the `ThisWorkbook` come from? Build (and display) the intended full file specification before the .SaveAs and try again.

**WRT Updated code:**

There is a difference between your:

```
cwd = fso.GetAbsolutePathName("*.*")
```

and Ansgar's:

```
cwd = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```

To get the Script's folder (as opposed to the current directory) use

```
fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

Comment: I changed the code but it still prompts me to save the and forces me to choose a location. In this example I am launching the .vbs from the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript you can't use the `ThisWorkbook` property. You have to obtain and use a reference to the workbook object:

```
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
WScript.Echo wb.Name
```

However, that won't help in your case, because you add a new empty workbook, so it doesn't have a path yet.

You can get the current working directory like this:

```
cwd = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
```

or like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
cwd = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```

I'd prefer the latter, since you can also use the `fso` object to build the path to the output file:

```
filename = fso.BuildPath(cwd, "output.xlsx")
```

And, as [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236618/1630171) already pointed out, `SaveAs` is a method, not a property, so you have to remove the `=` from that instruction:

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename
```

**Edit:** To create the output file in the same directory the script resides in, change

```
cwd = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
filename = fso.BuildPath(cwd, "output.xlsx")
```

into

```
scriptDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
filename = fso.BuildPath(scriptDir, "output.xlsx")
```

Although changing the variable name is not required, it's good practice to name variables according to their content.

Comment: I've made the updates but it is still prompting me to choose a directory upon running the script from the desktop.

Comment: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    cwd = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename = fso.BuildPath(cwd, "output.xlsx")
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    objExcel.Application.Quit

Comment: It is also keeping the save as name as Book1.xlsx

Comment: Dude, SaveAs() is a method.   1) filename = fso.BuildPath(cwd, "output.xlsx")  2) objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename

Comment: It is still prompting me to choose a directory upon running the script from the desktop. It is also keeping the save as name as Book1.xlsx.

Comment: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    cwd = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename=fso.BuildPath(cwd, "output.xlsx") 
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    objExcel.Application.Quit

Comment: There are 4 lines with 4 instructions in my answer (ignoring the `.CurrentDirectory` alternative). Just use those 4 lines. Don't get creative. If it still doesn't work, update your question with your modified code. Posting code in comments is a no-no, because the code becomes unreadable.

Comment: Please take a close look at the `GetAbsolutePathName` instruction in my answer and compare that to the `GetAbsolutePathName` instruction in your updated question. Pay particular attention to the arguments of both method calls.